# Err: Failed to deserialize user out of session

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to implement basic authentication procedures using passport js with mongodb and it's complimenting frameworks,however,when I try to log-in an existing user,the deserialization error pops and the app crashes.It works fine when trying to register new users.All the default get routes have been excluded from the snippet and only the secrets one is available as I cannot determine it's non-relevance with the error.

```
app.use(express.static("public"))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(session({
    secret:process.env.SECRET,
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
})
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose)

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
passport.use(User.createStrategy())
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser())
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser())


app.get("/secrets",(req,res)=>{
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.render("secrets")
    }else{
        res.redirect("/login")
    }
})

app.post("/register",(req,res)=> {
    console.log(req.body.password)
    User.register({username: req.body.username},req.body.password, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.redirect("/register")
        } else {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => {
                res.redirect("/secrets")
            })
        }
    })
})

app.post("/login",(req,res)=>{
    const user=new User({
        user:req.body.username,
        password:req.body.password
    })
    req.login(user,(err)=>{
        if(err){
            res.redirect("/register")
        }else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,()=>{
                res.redirect("/secrets")
            })
        }})
})
```

Comment: What is the error, that you get? Can you add the error message to your question?

Comment: Error: Failed to serialize user into session